# cytoscape js updating node label dynamically with fontawesome

Tags: javascript, html, cytoscape.js

**Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/ajhnmcrb/16/

**What is Needed:**
I want to dynamically change the content name of the node and I want to use font awesome icon as Unicode in it.

**Tries:**
If I use content: `'\uf173'` , font renders correctly. But If I want to update node label with new font Unicode, it does not work. it simply prints `\uf173` instead of font

I am using input `<input type="text" value="\uf173" id="title">` to change node with id e `cy.$('#e')` to change its content.

```
   $('#title').on('input', function() { 
         cy.$('#e').css({
          content:   $('#title').val()
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/ajhnmcrb/120/

I figured for font icons

1. append them to body and get its character using .content()
2. use char returned as is for label which is typeof string

`function font_to_char(classname) {
   var span = document.createElement('span');
   span.className = classname;
   span.style.display = 'none';
   document.body
     .insertBefore(span, document.body.firstChild);
   var char = window
     .getComputedStyle(span, ':before')
     .content
     .replace(/'|"/g, '');
   span.remove();
   return char;
 }`

Answer (score 1):

A unicode escape character should only work in HTML `value` if it's specified in the code.  If you type \uf173 in an input it has the value `'\\uf173'`.  You'll have to parse if you want to recognise a similar typed string as unicode escape value.  Or you'll have to have the user actually type the real value you want using some kind of OS system key sequence.

Or just append the value.  I wouldn't expect a user to be typing in things like that: `label: function( node ){ return '\uf173' + node.data('label'); }`